# How pass hyphen inside a curly braces in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`

```
<img src={poster.poster-image} alt="poster 1" class="h-28 w-28" />
```

`
poster-image is coming from api but iam getting an error saying image is not defined.
how to fix this?

Comment: Do `src={poster["poster-image"]}`.

Answer (score 3):

`poster.poster-image` is a subtraction expression (i.e. poster. poster - image).

To access a key that contains characters that cannot appear in an identifier, use brackets:

`poster["poster-image"]`